# Adding django-socketio to existing Apache/mod_wsgi/Django site

Tags: django, apache, socket.io, mod-wsgi

Can anyone provide or link to a tutorial for adding django-socketio functionality to an existing Django site that uses Apache and mod_wsgi?

Can they work in parallel or does the runserver_socketio command need to handle all requests?

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834028/django-socketio-and-apache) is related but offers little practical information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run the regular site behind a public facing server like Apache, with the runserver_socketio part just serving websockets on a separate port. As described in the question you linked to, you'll need to work out if it's possible to proxy websockets through your web server if that's a requirement for you, but as also mentioned the gevent server used by runserver_socketio is more than capable.

When running separate instances like this, the "out of band" functions won't work, as they depend on shared state:

```
django_socketio.broadcast(message)
django_socketio.broadcast_channel(message, channel)
django_socketio.send(session_id, message)
```

You'll also need to add the `SOCKETIO_PORT` to the regular Django project's settings so that it knows which port to use.

Comment: Can you please elaborate you answer. Where do these configs reside? Also what about the solutions posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733137/adding-socket-io-to-existing-django-wsgi-project?lq=1