# Adding Socket.IO to existing Django/WSGI project

Tags: django, apache, socket.io, mod-wsgi

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840175/adding-django-socketio-to-existing-apache-mod-wsgi-django-site) seems to be trying to do the same thing but the answer to his question isn't clear enough. I'm not all that familiar with setting up socket servers so I'm still a bit lost here. Has anyone accomplished this before? How do you spin up the socket server and keep it running?

I wanted to comment on his post and ask him if he had success but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final solution to this was using the built-in `runserver_socketio` command for the `manage.py` script, running on `0.0.0.0:9000`. I'm using Ubuntu so I made an upstart config to keep it alive. Seems to be working just fine running alongside my Apache/WSGI server. If anyone has a better solution please speak up.

Comment: My guess is that is a dev server solution. If its anything like the runserver command, it isnt meant for production use. For all I know maybe they intend for that to be a production solution. But I would think you are supposed to end up serving it through a full fledged wsgi process.

Comment: ^^ That's exactly what I was thinking. But I can't seem to find a better solution...

Comment: You could post how you made a upstart config, though.

Answer (score 0):

A approach I came up with was using the wsgi the apache uses to instance a thread that just calls the runserver_socketio command. That's not, for sure, the best approach. But if someone finds a better solution. Let us know in this post.

```
def init_socketio():
    os.system('python manage.py runserver_socketio 0.0.0.0:9000')

socketio_thread = Thread(target=init_socketio, args=())
socketio_thread.start()
```